# parent node to contain the sum of all the child node data

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion, tree

I've created a dynamic tree for web application. My tree structure looks like:

```
id     name     pid     data1     data2

1      Item1    0 

2      Item2    1       70        45

3      Item3    0   

4      Item3    1       56        48

3      Item3    3       34        48
 ........
```

The parent node doesn't contain any values for data1 and data2. I've created the recursive list for the tree. But now what i need to do is show the the values of data1 and data2 of all the child nodes into the values of data1 and data2 in parent node.

The tree is multilevel. How can i add to each parent the values of its child nodes? I am using C# btw. thanks

Update:

```
 public class MyTree
{
    public MyTree()
    {
        children = new List<MyTree>();
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
    public int pid { get; set; }
    public decimal? data1 { get; set; }
    public decimal? data2 { get; set; }            
    public IList<MyTree> children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the Node class that you're using? The answer will involve using this to recursively traverse the tree.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Please see the update section for Node class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following member variable/updated property pair will give an explicit value if it's been set, or a recursive sum of all the children's values if it hasn't:

```
private decimal? _data1;
public decimal? data1
{
    get
    {
        if (_data1.HasValue)
            return _data1;
        // This needs System.Linq but can be done manually.
        return children.Sum(c => c.data1);
    }
    set { _data1 = value; }
}
```

(Similarly for `data2`.)

It doesn't stop you from explicitly setting a value on an element with children.

Comment: I'm using recursive functions to set the values in the node. So it is setting the value 0 to all the parents. Also the above code seems to set the values of children to its parent. Does it work to set the sum of children of children(if it has) and so on to the root or every higher parent?

Comment: Sorry for my last comment. Your solution works great. Thankx. Let me do some more testing before i accept your answer.